# Oracle SQL add foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

These are the two tables I currently have.

```
CREATE TABLE WORK
(
CODE varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE TEACHER
(
ID varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
NAME varchar(255),
GENDER varchar(255)
);
```

And I'm trying to add `CODE` to the `TEACHER` table as a foreign key. This is what I tried to use.

```
ALTER TABLE TEACHER
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CODE)
REFERENCES WORK(CODE);
```

However when I execute this it says:

> Error at line 2: ORA-00904: "CODE": invalid identifier

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong, and provide a possible fix?

Answer (score 8):

First you need to add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE TEACHER ADD CODE VARCHAR(255);
```

Then add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TEACHER ADD FOREIGN KEY (CODE) REFERENCES WORK(CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE TEACHER
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CODE)
REFERENCES WORK(CODE);
```

What you are doing, you are trying to add foreign key from teacher.code to work.code. You don't have teacher.code.